# I want to build a small JS library with some utility functions like jQuery. The coding approach below is correct or any other better-way of doing this

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to build a small JS library with some utility functions like jQuery. 
The coding approach below is correct or any other better way of doing this.
I want to hear suggestions like the recommended approach or any design pattern to follow.

```
function $(selector){
    const self = {
        element:document.querySelector(selector),
        elements:document.querySelectorAll(selector),
        hide:()=>{
            self.elements.forEach(element => {
                element.style.display =  'none';
            });
            return self;
        },
        show:()=>{
            self.elements.forEach(element => {
                element.style.display =  'initial';
            });
            return self;
        },
        on:(event,callback)=>{
            self.elements.forEach(element => {
                element.addEventListener(event,callback);
            });
            return self;
        },
        attr:(attribute,value = null)=>{
            if(value != null){
                self.elements.forEach(element => {
                    element.setAttribute(attribute,value);
                });
                return self;
            }
            else
                self.element.getAttribute(attribute)
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: one doubt, if you are using `jquery` in your library, why do you want to create new library with same functionality?

Comment: I am not using jQuery. I am trying to build a library like JQuery. If using JQuery confuse you, I just want to build a JS library with my own utility functions...